# Надо двоеточие или тире

Tags: пунктуация

В свою очередь, спрошу: Аня, Вы журналист?

Answer (score 2):

***В свою очередь спрошу: "Аня, Вы журналист?"***

Думаю так.

Answer (score 2):

*В свою очередь спрошу: "Аня, вы журналист?"*

Это прямая речь. Могло бы быть бессоюзным предложением вот в таком варианте: "В свою очередь спрошу: журналист ли вы, Аня?" Тогда оно легко трансформируется в сложноподчинённое: "В свою очередь спрошу о том, журналист ли вы".

Также об обороте "в свою очередь". В данном случае он использован в значении "в ответ" и вводной конструкцией не является. "Авторским" тоже всё подряд называть нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, это переписка в интернете, а не прямая речь. Тогда я бы оставила как написано:

> В свою очередь, спрошу: Аня, Вы журналист?

Comment: Даже если так, то что это меняет?

Comment: Главное, что при переписке это не прямая речь. Это то же самое, как если бы было написано: "... позвольте задать Вам вопрос. Аня, Вы журналист?" 


Но при прямой речи, конечно, кавычки нужны. Я подойду к ней и спрошу: "Аня, Вы журналист?"

Comment: Да бог пока с ними, с кавычками. Прямая речь может и без них оформляться.  
Тире откуда? И запятая после "очередь"?  

*Опять скажу: никто не обнимет необъятного! (Прутков, Козьма Петрович).*

Comment: Про тире не знаю, не в курсе. А запятая здесь авторская. Без контекста не решить, нужна она или нет. Вполне может и быть.

Comment: Мотивация запитой какая может быть у автора? Контекст - по Вашему выбору. Не может же автор ставить его просто потому, что "моя запятая - куда хочу, туда и ставлю". Или я чего-то недопонимаю?  
Кстати, я крепко засомневался, можно ли вообще утверждать, что это не прямая речь. Такое ощунение, что тут вся фраза - прямая речь, включая пояснение. Разве в диалоге каждая отдельная фраза его участников не является прямой речью?

Comment: @behemothus, в этом нашем с Вами диалоге Вы почему не пишете свои посты в кавычках?